# Extract Competitor Information from Opportunity

Tags: opportunity, data-extract

Salesforce Opportunities has the possibility to record competitor data for an opportunity. On an opportunity this is represented as a related list which allows you to select a competitor and then type the strengths and weaknesses of this competitor. I would like to extract this data now, but have no idea how, because it does not seem to be an object.

Any ideas? Tia, Lily.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at this through [the workbench](https://workbenchbench.developerforce.com/), this is indeed an sObject, and it's called `OpportunityCompetitor`.

If you're using the Salesforce-provided Apex Data Loader, you'll need to check "Show All Salesforce Objects" to have `OpportunityCompetitor` appear in the list of objects.

If you want to simply find all competitors related to a given `Opportunity`, you can use a parent-child subquery (aka. Left Outer Join). The relationship name is `OpportunityCompetitors`

```
[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM OpportunityCompetitors) FROM Opportunity]
```